# Can I use std::set<std::string> as a default parameter for a function?

Tags: c++

I'm new to this and now sure whether this is doable. I want to add a argument of `std::set<std::string>` to a function, and set its default value to be `NULL`, to avoid impact on previous uses.

So basically,

```
func(int a); turns into  
func(int a, std::set<std::string> & temp = NULL);
```

but this will give me an error `"error C2440: 'default argument' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'std::set<_Kty> &'"`

Can anybody help me on this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure you can have a reference to `NULL`. (As opposed to a pointer.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to set the default to `NULL`, you'd have to be passing an `std::set<std::string>*`, not a reference to a value type.

Furthermore, if you are passing a non-pointer type and you want to assign *any default value at all*, it has to be a `const` reference, because you can't (advisably!) assign a temporary to it otherwise.

So your choices for "default" values are basically:

```
std::set<std::string>* = NULL
```

or:

```
const std::set<std::string>& = std::set<std::string>()
```

or option 3, using function overloading more directly:

```
void myfunction() {dothing(0);}
void myfunction(std::set<std::string>& optional_param) 
{ dothing(optional_param.size()); }
```

or option 4, having a corresponding `bool` indicating whether parameter is "set":

```
void myfunction(std::set<std::string>& param, bool param_has_meaning=true) {}
```

It looks like you're already on the track to the third option. You just need to write two definitions, one with and one without the parameter.

Comment: "it has to be a `const` reference": Does the standard specify this?

Comment: @user946850- Yes, since lvalue references cannot bind to temporary objects, since they aren't lvalues.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a `NULL` *reference* in C++.

The simplest way would be to have a dummy empty `set`:

```
std::set<std::string> empty;
void func(int a, std::set<std::string>& temp = empty)
{
    // ...
}
```

You can then call:

```
    func(1);
```

Neater, still, would be to use function overloading to create a wrapper so that you have no need to default:

```
void func(int a, std::set<std::string>& temp)
{
}

void func(int a)
{
    std::set<std::string> empty;
    func(a, empty);
}

    // And then...
    func(1);
```

All this assumes that if you pass in a `set` you're going to modify it somehow. It's not clear from your question what your intention is but I've made the assumption on the basis that your reference is non-`const`. If I've miscalculated, then the answer is even simpler:

```
void func(int a, const std::set<std::string>& temp = std::set<std::string>())
{
}
```

Comment: +1 also worth mentionig that you could use default parameters with a const set. `void func(int a, std::set<std::string> const& temp = std::set<std::string>())`

Comment: Thanks @LokiAstari. I've enhanced my answer following your comment.

Comment: If you are going to modify `temp`, then `std::set<std::string>& temp = empty` is probably not a good idea. You could modify `empty` (through `temp`), which would make `empty` no longer actually be empty. Furthermore, any modifications to `empty` would not be thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea - using a reference. However, a reference cannot be NULL by default, like a pointer can. Therefore, what you probably want to do is overload the function so that you use `void func(int a)` when you don't want to pass a set as a parameter and use `void func( int a, std::set<std::string>& temp)`

This way, you can actually provide two separate implementations - one that works on a set and one that doesn't. From a usage point of view, it would have the same effect as a default parameter. From a coding point of view, each implementation would have a clearer purpose.

If you're not going to be modifying the set, might I suggest using a const reference instead:

```
void func( int a, const std::set<std::string>& temp )
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will give you an empty `set` object:

```
std::set<std::string>()
```

Comment: thanks, i changed it in both prototype and and definition, but now the definition line will give me _"error C2572: *** redefinition of default parameter :"_

Comment: don't use it in the definition, only in the prototype